# Custom Search Engine - Google search results , click it open in same tab

Tags: html

why doesn't this display in same tab.I want show it in same tab when  click search result.

```
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<form action="http://mywebsite/googlesearch.html" id="searchForm" method="get">
 <img src="images/google.png" alt="Smiley face" height="40" width="100"></br>  
 <input id="search_text_box" maxlength="256" name="q" placeholder="google search"/> 
 <input id="search_button" type="submit" value="Search"/></form>         
   <script>(function() { var cx = 'apicode'; 
   var gcse = document.createElement('script'); 
   gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; 
   gcse.async = true; 
   gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
   '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx; 
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s); })(); <gcse:searchresults-only linktarget="_parent"></gcse:searchresults-only></script> </body>
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with a GSA

Answer (score 0):

I find it!
 use this to refesh page
_blank  Opens the linked document in a new window or tab.
_self   Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked.(default)
_parent Opens the linked document in the parent frame.

find code

replace code